# Why does this only return values 1&0?

Tags: java, return-value

I've tried editing this a few times now, it seems to me to have no errors that I can find...
The original problem was to input an Index number and find the fibbonaci number at that index...
The program as it is now looks fine to me but returns, for the first two values, 1 then 1 again, and likewise for 0.
What can I do?

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main2 {

    public int FibIterative(int i){
        System.out.print.ln("Enter the index of the series.");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();            
        if (n<0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No number in the series is negative");
        } else if (n==0||n==1) {
            return n;
        }
        int prev=0;
        int prevPrev=1;
        int current=0
        for (int x=0; x<n; x++){
            current= prev+ prevPrev;
            prevPrev= prev;
            prev= current;
        }
        return current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could your please add more details in your question ? What language ? Your code etc...

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: What is `i` argument? Why it's unused?

Comment: i argument is there because otherwise it would be n, then I don't know how to add scanner to n variable, 

Comment: have you rebuild your class after you changed code? your code looks fine, and it works fine. only thing what i can think of is you are running wrong code

Comment: No I have rebuilt the code and checked it a million times

Comment: I cannot see why it returns only 1 or 2...

Comment: I will re write it in a new class to check

Comment: are you using any ide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :)

```
    int p=0;
    int c=1;
    int sum=0;
    String fibo="";

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            sum =c+p;
            //System.out.println(sum);
            p=c;
            c=sum;
            fibo=fibo+sum;

        }
        return fibo;
```

Comment: Thanks rahul will try, :) However I think error is in my build path and run error as someone else said it was running a different method, now I have to debug the file...